# Problema al Obtener mi ubicación actual Android

Tags: android-studio, geolocalización

Estoy desarrollando una app que me muestre mi ubicación actual, el problema viene al usar `GetLastKnowLocation` ya que como sabemos muestra la ultima ubicación registrada, o retorna `null` en caso de no existir.

No he podido encontrar la manera de traer mi ubicación actual, ya he usado `requestLocationUpdates` y he probado soluciones que plantean en foros pero al parecer ninguno funciona como lo deseo. De igual manera tengo todos los permisos en `Manifest`.

¿Tienen alguna solución?, necesito que sea mi ubicación actual.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar de esta forma

```
private fun ValidarPermisosUbicacion():Boolean{

    val hayUbicacionPrecisa = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permisoFineLocation) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    val hayUbicacionOrdinaria = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permisoCoarseLocation) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

    return hayUbicacionPrecisa && hayUbicacionOrdinaria
}

private fun iniciarLocationRequest(){
    locationRequest = LocationRequest()
    locationRequest?.interval = 10000
    locationRequest?.fastestInterval
    locationRequest?.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
}


    var callback = object: LocationCallback(){
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?){
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult)
            if (mMap != null){
                mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
                mMap.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = true
                for (ubicacion in locationResult?.locations!!){
                    //Toast.makeText(applicationContext, ubicacion.latitude.toString() + " / " + ubicacion.longitude.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    MIPOSICION = LatLng(ubicacion.latitude, ubicacion.longitude)
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(MIPOSICION))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fusedLocationClient?.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, callback, null)
}
```

Comment: Esto es en Kotlin, me parece que el OP lo requiere en Java.

Comment: Asi es, lo requiero en java, alguna solución?